# Converting two 8 bit data to one 16 bit data getting zero

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with a code for a project that I'm writing. I'm trying to combine two bytes of data into one 16 bit number in little endian (ie. 00 02 into 02 00 in hex or 0000 0000 0000 0010 to 0000 0010 0000 0000 in binary). I found an arithmetic solution for it where (most significant bit * 256) + least significant bit. However, whenever I try to do this, I get a zero on the output. Can anybody figure out what I'm doing wrong here? I'm running out of ideas. Thanks!

```
int main (int argc, char **argv){

int fd;
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(512);
struct fileSystem_info fat_12;

//Check if argv[1] exists
if(argc > 2){
    printf("Error: The file does not exist. \n");
}

//Open the file
fd = open("fat_volume.dat", O_RDONLY, S_IROTH);
if (fd == -1){
    printf("Error: Opening the file was unsuccessful \n");
}

//Read the file
if (read(fd,buffer,512) < 0){
    printf("Error: Read was unsuccessful \n");
}
else{
    printf("Read is successful \n" );
}

//Converts two 8 bit data to one 16 bit data
int converter(int mostSignificant_bit, int leastSignificant_bit){
    return((mostSignificant_bit * 256) + leastSignificant_bit);
}

//Parse data
unsigned char first_byte = buffer[11]; //(raw byte that is read from a hex editor is 00)
unsigned char second_byte = buffer[12]; //(raw byte that is read from  a hex editor is 02)
unsigned char test = converter( (int)second_byte, (int)first_byte);
printf("%hhu \n", first_byte);
//outputs 0 
printf("%hhu \n", second_byte);
//outputs 2 
printf("%hhu \n", test);
//outputs 0

}
```

Comment: Change `unsigned char test` to `unsigned int test`. Also, I'd use `unsigned int` for your convert function parameters and return type unless there's a reason you need them to be signed. To be even more strict and limit to 16 bit values, use the `uint16_t` type.

Comment: Is it advisable to change all the unsigned char to unsigned int? Also, my compiler is telling me that uint16_t is an unknown type.

Comment: You might need to include `types.h`.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the `#include <types.h>` on my compiler. Does this mean my compiler does not support it?

Comment: I used `#include <stdint.h>` and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your types are char, `test` needs to be larger than char. See the two ^^ changes below.

```
unsigned char test = converter( (int)second_byte, (int)first_byte);
         ^^^^ should be int
printf("%hhu \n", first_byte);
//outputs 0 
printf("%hhu \n", second_byte);
//outputs 2 
printf("%hhu \n", test);
         ^^^ should be u
```

Also, change convert to:

```
unsigned converter(unsigned mostSignificant_bit, unsigned leastSignificant_bit);
```

Comment: Keep going Charlie.  _5K may get you that blender._

Comment: Would it be advisable if I change all of the unsigned char in my code to unsigned int? What would be the main difference? Would it just change the length of reserved memory for the different data types?

Comment: No, I would keep it the way it is since those other variables actually are byte size. The common C idiom for converter is "(mostSignificant_bit << 8) | leastSignificant_bit". What you do works, but the other way is more explicit.

Comment: Can you please explain the changes that you made? Also, what is the difference between unsigned char and unsigned int? Finally, why did you use just unsigned on the converter type? Thanks!

Comment: In most computers, unsigned char is one byte, unsigned int is 4 or 8 bytes. So the int has more bits to hold the data than char. My suggestion for the unsigned types in converter has to do with sign extension. While it wasn't really a problem in your case, it's generally better to do bit manipulation with unsigned numbers because sometime sign extension with fill your upper bits with ones.

Comment: @CharlieBurns - no problem - points, blender, margarita.  Its all good.

Answer (score 2):

You can acccomplish this simply by shifting over the msb and doing a bitwise or with the lsb.

```
uint16_t value = (uint16_t)(msb << 8) | lsb;
```

Comment: my compiler is telling me that uint16_t is an unknown type. Should I add a specific library for this?